# Битрикс: Выбор раздела для поиска

Tags: php, битрикс

В битриксе есть компонент "Стандартная страница поиска".
Хочу его кастомизировать так, чтобы была возможность выбрать поиск по разделам.

Пример:
Есть разделы: смартфоны, планшеты, компьютеры.

Если при поиске не выбрать раздел, то должен искать везде. А если выбрать раздел смартфоны, то должен искать товары только из раздела смартфоны, а товары остальных разделов не должен выводить.

Пробовал делать так:

```
<?
global $searchFilter;
$searchFilter = Array("section_id"=>"5");
?>

<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:search.page", ".default", array(
    "RESTART" => "N",
    "NO_WORD_LOGIC" => "N",
    "CHECK_DATES" => "N",
    "USE_TITLE_RANK" => "N",
    "DEFAULT_SORT" => "rank",
         "USE_FILTER" => "Y",
    "FILTER_NAME" => "searchFilter",

        ...

        ));?>
```

`"section_id"=>"5"` - это `id` раздела "Смартфоны", для примера.

Но не реагирует.

Что еще можно делать для поиска по выбранным разделам?

Что можно добавить в `result_modifier` для вышеописанной задачи?

Comment: В целом механизм описан тут https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=5196 , насколько я понимаю

Answer (score 0):

а можно код шаблона привести? А то вызова как-то не особо интересен. И если мне не изменяет память, то настроить разделы вы можете в меню компонента. И стесняюсь спросить, а зачем фильтр на search.page?

Скрин интерфейса
http://joxi.ru/Vm6le0zHa8dqAZ

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/blogs/oracle/2687.php здесь все подробно описано.

У вас нет результата, потому что индексация сайта происходит без учета разделов.

Необходимо добавить поле для заполнения `section_id` , после этого сделать переиндексацию сайта и только потом можно будет обращаться по этому полю в `searchFilter`.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -1):

Если Вы делаете поиск товаров, то это реализуется например следующим образом:

1. Ставите компонент search.page в arResult шаблона которого приходит массив в котором указан id найденного элемента и его инфоблок.
2. В этом же шаблоне вызываете catalog.section, в который в arrFilter передаёте найденные id и свои дополнительные параметры и получаете фильтрованый список товаров